# C# Is this a misuse of generic interfaces?

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I want to use several generic interfaces together as a reusable subsystem.

Here are the interfaces:

```
interface ICollection<TElement> : IEnumerable<TElement> {
    TElement this[Int32 index] { get; }
    TElement Add();
}

interface IElement<TCollection> {
    TCollection Collection { get; }
}
```

I would like to use generic constraints on TElement and TCollection to be able to 1) enforce the expected use of the interfaces, and 2) use the implementing type as a method return type.

```
interface ICollection<TCollection, TElement> : IEnumerable<TElement>
   where TCollection : ICollection<TCollection, TElement>
   where TElement : IElement<TCollection, TElement> {

    TElement this[Int32 index] { get; }
    TElement Add();
}

interface IElement<TCollection, TElement>
    where TCollection : ICollection<TCollection, TElement>
    where TElement : IElement<TCollection, TElement> {

    TCollection Collection { get; }
}
```

It compiles, but is this a misuse of generic interfaces?

---

EDIT:

Thank you for the comments.  I am going to avoid code like the second example above.

Is there any cleaner way to achieve my second goal, of using the implementing type as a method return type of an interface method?

This will not compile, but is basically what I want to do:

```
interface IThing {
    IThing GetThing();
}

class Thing : IThing {
    Thing GetThing();    
}
```

Comment: I find it hard to believe that the benefits of this approach are going to outweigh the costs. Have you written any more code than just this? Even declaring a class that implements your collection interfaces requires more effort than it should.

Comment: I've used this approach a number of times. It's effectively the Gang Of Four "Bridge Pattern" using generics - two independent classes that extend independently, but remain cohesively interrelated.

Comment: I would say yes, to your question. I struggle to see any point to what you are doing. It reminds me of the old days in C where people would typedef all the base types into something specific to their modules.

Comment: @mike z:  Yes, I started trying to declare the implementing classes and got a bad "smell", so I came here.  The actual system I'm trying to construct is actually more complicated and has 4 main interacting interfaces.  I'm trying to absorb SOLID practices like coding to interfaces into my workflow, but in this scenario, it seems to me like the interdependency this interface configuration is creates completely negates the potential flexibility of "coding to interfaces".

Comment: As to the part in your edit, the standard way to do something like that is via an explicit interface implementation. You have `public Thing GetThing() { /* whatever */ }` and then `IThing IThing.GetThing() { return GetThing(); }`.

Comment: Wow, I really over-complicated that one.  Thanks.